# Permissions required scale up environment composer 2?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I already have an environment running, but want to scale up the machine sizes. But keep getting a very similar error to this:

```
    UPDATE operation on this environment failed 3 minutes ago with the
following error message:
Composer Backend timed out. Currently running tasks are [stage:
CP_COMPOSER_AGENT_RUNNING
description: "No agent response published."
response_timestamp {
  seconds: 1618203503
  nanos: 291000000
}
].
```

The [gcp docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/troubleshooting-updates-upgrades) say that the service account doesn't have required permissions. I check required permissions also in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-control#cross-project). My personal account and service already have the role Environment and Storage Object Administrator. And the service account already has the role Cloud Composer v2 API Service Agent Extension. I don't understand which permission am I missing.

Service account that the composer uses has roles:

```
Cloud Composer v2 API Service Agent Extension
Editor
Environment and Storage Object Administrator
Service Account User
```

And my personal account has roles:

```
Editor
Environment and Storage Object Administrator
Service Account User
Storage Admin
Viewer
```

Comment: Please include details of the command(s) that you're running and details of the IAM policy that confirms your assertion that the roles are correct.

Comment: I am doing it through the UI

Comment: Are you using a Shared VPC?

Comment: no, no shared VPC

Comment: Can you try changing the Editor Role to Owner role just to make the upgrade and then return it back to Editor? If the error persists it is probably that there is a firewall configuration that is causing that error.